Higher-Order Expansion Form
I came across something that was described as a "third order expansion" I'm having trouble understanding.
The function is $$ f(X_t)=\frac{X^\sigma}{\sigma} $$
The expansion is done around $X=X^*$ and they define $x = \ln(X) - \ln(X^*)$. The expansion is written as
$$f(X^*)+X^*f'(X^*)\left[x+\frac{1}{2!}\sigma x^2 + \frac{1}{3!}\sigma^2x^3 \right] $$
It sort of makes sense aesthetically but I was hoping someone could point me to a reference on deriving it this way.

Well, the first time I asked ChatGPT it didn't get it but now it did I think. Exciting times!..
As I'm about to post I see the disclaimer about LLM generated answers, so I guess I'll summarize.
It seems like the form is partially specific to $f(\cdot)$ and then there's this trick
$$
\ln(X) = \ln(X^*) + x \implies X = X^* e^{x}
$$
which allows for the exponential taylor expansion to be used. Specifically,
$$
f(X) = \dfrac{X^\sigma}{\sigma} = \dfrac{(X^* e^{x})^\sigma}{\sigma} = \dfrac{(X^*)^\sigma e^{\sigma x}}{\sigma}=f(X^*)e^{\sigma x}
$$
and then because
$$
\sigma f(X^*) = X^* f'(X^*)
$$
you can get the form of the answer.
